# Error 500 in PHP script on GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have a fairly simple PHP script running on GAE that accepts a request from a client, makes a call to the Google Drive api to get an Access token using a fixed refresh token and then returns that access token to the client.

This script has been operational for over three years and unchanged for two but today it has started returning error 500.  From the logs the full error is "Google_IO_Exception: Couldn't resolve host 'accounts.google.com'
Google_IO_Abstract->makeRequest (/base/data/home/apps/s~b....cs/3-0....5/Google/IO/Curl.php)".

It is only on GAE it fails.  If I run the script locally it still works okay.

There are two parts to the script.  Firstly it receives the request:

```
if (isset($_GET['refresh'])) {
  // Get new access token from refresh token
  try {
    $client->refreshToken($refresh_token);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
  }
  catch (Google_Auth_Exception $e) {
    .....
  }
}
```

and then, having retrieved the access token, it returns it to the client:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    try {
      $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
      header("response:" . $_SESSION['access_token']);
      exit;
    }
    catch (Google_Auth_Exception $e) {
      .....
    }
  }
```

Has anything changed in GAE?  I have to admit it's a long time since I've had to look at this code and was wondering if something had been deprecated but I have been unable to see anything relevant.  Any thoughts would be welcome.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Try logging into your console and check the logs

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  Google suddenly decided it required a billing account in order to use cURL.php.  Use of cURL was added in Feb 2015 with php5.5 so why it suddenly decided, 2 years later, without any warning, to insist on a billing account is anybody's guess.  For expediency's sake, I just changed the config to force use of IO.Stream.  All working okay now.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in an App Engine software update that has since been rolled back, so your original code should work again.  Sorry!